# stats, t-test, lists, and only one output

Tags: python-3.x

t-tests have been yielding just one output...but I want 10 t-tests.
Each t-test should compare each one of the 10 values in list to 0.

I have tried the below:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
list2=[0.10415380403918414, 0.09142102934943379, 0.08340408682911706, 0.07791383429638124, 0.0738177221067812, 0.07111840615962706, 0.0673345711222398, 0.06431875318226271, 0.06074216826770115, 0.052948996685723906]
print(scipy.stats.ttest_ind(list2,[0]*10))
```

Each t-test should compare each one of the 10 values in list to 0. that is, I should get 10 t-test comparison, so 10 t-tests should be outputted

All of this is to say: I am seeking 10 rows of output (each corresponding to a unique t-test, therefore I am seeking  10 t-tests), but the code I have now just provides me with one row output, i.e. just one test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listofzeros=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(10):
    print(scipy.stats.ttest_ind(list2,listofzeros))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to use stats.ttest_ind and create a list of zeros with the same length as the sample. You just can use stats.ttest_1samp, as follows:

```
print(scipy.stats.ttest_1samp(list2,0,))
```

That will lead to the same result but without tweaking returning the r-static value and the p-value for the mean of the input sample not returning the results per value per sample.

To be more comprehensive, The t-test is used to determine whether the sample "mean" is statistically significantly different from the population "mean".

What you are trying to do is to perform a two-sample T-test which will work on the mean of the two lists, not on every two associated values of the two samples.

Comment: No, I want 10 rows of output (each corresponding to a unique t-test), this code and my code just provides me with one row output, i.e. just one test

Comment: To do so, you need 10 samples to perform 10 t-tests on it. you are providing just one sample. The algorithm will get the mean of the 10 values and calculate the r-static and p-value. Got it?